# Jquery empty value for radio when submitting form subsequent times

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im having an issue where Im getting an empty value for the value of a radio when my ajax form is submitted subsequent times.

Sequentially this is what happens:

1. User selects a radio and submits form
2. Get the value of the selected radio `var enable = $('input[name=enable]:checked').attr('value');`
3. Post the value via AJAX `data: { 'enable' : enable, },`

That all works fine. However if the user submits the form again the value of the radio is empty, nothing is submitted.

I am using styles and Jquery to hide the 'standard' radios and replace them with styled versions. With the style turned off, I can see that the radios are being selected correctly, however no value is submitted.

I can post some more code if need be. Thanks.

```
<form method="post" id="add-form" class="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<label>Enable Location</label>
<input type="radio" name="location_enable" id="location_enable" value="enable" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="location_enable" id="location_disable" value="disable" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Validate the form

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $("#add-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    location_enable: { required: true }
                },
                success: function(span) { 
                    span.html(" ").addClass("checked"); 
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $('#add-form').submitForm();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Post the data

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.fn.submitForm = function() {
                    var location_enable = $('input[name=location_enable]:checked').attr('value');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { 'location_enable' : location_enable },
                        url: 'script.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function($data) {
                            var result = $data.result;
                            var msg = $data.msg;

                            if (result == "success") {
                                formMessageDisplay(msg, result);
                                $(':input', '#add-form').each( function() {
                                    // Set the values to empty
                                    $(':input').val('');
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                formMessageDisplay(msg, result);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function($data) {
                            formMessageDisplay('<?php echo AJAX_ERROR; ?>', result);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        </script>
```

On the first submission if the user selected 'enable' AJAX will post 'enable' as the value to script.php. Without reloading the page if the user submits the form again AJAX posts an empty value even is the user has selected 'enable'.

Sorry, havent used jsFiddle before.

Within Firebug this  is the output from two submissions without reloading the page.

```
json_action addEloc
location_address    Test
location_desc   Test
location_enable enable
location_loc    Test
location_map    enable
location_name   Testing radio
location_postcode   Test
location_state  QLD
```

Note the two 'enables' from the radio fields.

Second submission:

```
json_action addEloc
location_address    Test
location_desc   Test
location_enable 
location_loc    Test
location_map    
location_name   Testing radio
location_postcode   Test
location_state  QLD
```

There was no value for the two radios on the second submission.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)  with necessary data

Comment: **user submit the form again** means?? after page refresh?

Comment: The form is posted to an ajax script so there is no page refresh

Comment: NO, I mean  user again submit? is it not redundant?

Comment: Not at all. The user enters data into the form, the form is submitted via AJAX and the form is cleared. The user can then enter new data into the form and submit this without refreshing the page. All the form fields are working fine except for the radios.

Comment: Maybe double quotes: $('input[name="location_enable"]:checked').attr('value'); This only one difference from my similar working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs due to your this script

```
if (result == "success") {
                formMessageDisplay(msg, result);
                $(':input', '#add-form').each( function() {
                    // Set the values to empty
                     $(':input').val('');
                });
}
```

You are setting '' to the all input type elements

```
$(':input').val('');
```

that's why radio button values will also be set to '', and will return blank response as it is returning now until you refresh the page.

Instead of doing this you can use [reset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) function to reset form values.

```
$('#add-form').reset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to use **document.getElementById("add-form").reset();** but thats exactly what I needed